# dynamically add a constraint to rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints, monkeypatching

I want to write a plugin that need to do a monkey patch to add a constraint on all routes defined at rails application routes.rb

i try to do the following code in my monkey patch but this doesn't work. What is the right way?

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  RedmineApp::Application.routes.routes.each do |route|
    route.app.constraints << lambda{ |request| request.subdomains.first == 'admin' }
  end
end
```

Comment: i don't think that this is a good idea. what exactly is the use case here?

Comment: i need to write a plugin for a rails app and i want to change some constraints on routes from my plugin

Answer (score 0):

From RoR guide: Advanced Constraints:

> 'you can provide an object that responds to matches?'
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

```
TwitterClone::Application.routes.draw do
  match "*path" => "blacklist#index",
    :constraints => BlacklistConstraint.new
end
```

Comment: i need to change the route after routes.rb definitions